# Installing Certificate for CurrenUser/LocalMachine with no AdminRights?

Tags: powershell, certificate, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to install an UWP App on win10.
I want to automate the whole installing Process(install Certificate, Dependencies etc...)

So I Worte a little batch file that calls 2 Powershell scripts.
One installs the dependencies(checks if they're already installed).
The other one installs the Certificate and Adds the App to the system.

I am adding the Certificate to:

```
certutil -Enterprise -addstore "TrustedPublisher" .\cert.crt
certutil -Enterprise -addstore "Root" .\cert.crt
Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher -FilePath .\cert.crt
Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -FilePath .\cert.crt
Add-AppxPackage -Path .\app.appxbundle
```

Now the Thing is that my client wants me to do that with no Admin Rights.

Therefore I thought installing the for the CurrentUser instead would work, as installing ther cert there doesn't need Admin rights.

So I changed my Script like this

```
certutil -addstore -user -f "TrustedPublisher" .\cert.crt
certutil -addstore -user -f "Root" .\cert.crt
Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher -FilePath .\cert.crt
Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root -FilePath .\cert.crt
Add-AppxPackage -Path .\app.appxbundle
```

Also tried to add to "TrustedPeople" and "My" locations.

Installing the Certificate with no Admin rights worked fine. But installing the App itself failed with the Error.

> "Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x800B0109, A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider"

So the Certificate was kinda found but its not trusted.
So my questions are:

1. Why does the System not "trust" the Cert even when install it in "CurrentUSer/TrutedPublisher"(difference to LocalMachine/TrustedPublisher) ?
2. Is there a way to install the Cert to localMachine without Admin Rights?
3. Can I install the App by directing it to the installed cert in CurrentUser?

I am new to the whole Deployment stuff on Windows,  so I hope those Questions make sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the app is installed to the -system-, then it would be validating
   against the LocalMachine/TrustedPublisher. This is a basic security
   mechanism to prevent a random user from bypassing the security by
   "trusting" a cert and installing a random malicious piece of software without
   admin privileges; which could then be run by another user.
2. The correct way to get the Cert installed "without admin rights" is to use Group Policy to install a certificate see [Distribute Certificates to Client Computers by Using Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy)
3. No. Don't try to bypass the security. Basics are, you need an Admin to either install the cert in the LocalMachine/TrustedPublisher or to install the app. The easiest is to use a GPO to install the Cert first.

Comment: First off, Thanks for the answer. The GPO stuff must be done from the Company itself right? I don't have any access to their Domain or anything. So just give them the cert and let the system admin in the Company do it? or is there a way for me to do this via Powersehll but than again I would probably need admin rights to change the Group Policy I guess. right?

Comment: Exactly. Give them the certificate, and the sysadmin would be able to easily set up a GPO to get automatically installed. You are right, you can use PowerShell to install the certificate (and ironically it's really easy), but you won't get around needing to install it as an administrator.