# C#.NET MAUI - app works on PC where created but does not trust certificate on other PCs

Tags: c#, certificate, maui-windows

I have a MAUI app which is built and published for Windows (NOT for Android, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047509/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-in-a-net-maui-project-trying-t) is not my case). It works on the PC where it is created and published but when trying to install on the clean OS (VirtualBox) I get
[the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKNs8.png).

I have even turned on developer mode and running unsigned scripts and installed the certificate that goes near the app into the "Trusted Root Certification Centers" (what, of course, the normal user most probably won't ever do) but the error remains. The app itself is very typical, nothing extraordinary. Is it possible to fix this error without huge payments?

Comment: Did choose to the current user not the local machine when you installed the certificate? If so you can try to choose the local machine. In addition, did you try to install the app on the other windows pc instead of the VirtualBox?

Comment: Hello @LiyunZhang-MSFT! Yes, I somewhy had chosen the current user. Now I have tried installing that certificate to the "Trusted Root Certification Centers" for the local machine and it works, but is there a solution for the normal users, especially those who are afraid of giving Admin rights to the unknown apps? Also, I cannot try to install the app on the other Windows PC since I have just a PC and a notebook, and both have Visual Studio with all developer tweaks, and I don't have the clean OS outside of the Virtual Box.

Comment: There is no way for the current user. All the sample code in the official document about the [Installing Test Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-test-certificates) choose the local machine.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant not the "current user" in the certificates but the real end users - are all they necessary to install the certificate in their system with Admin rights?

Comment: Yes, the Admin right is necessary, you can refer to this case about [Installing Certificate for CurrenUser/LocalMachine with no AdminRights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866722/installing-certificate-for-currenuser-localmachine-with-no-adminrights).